# White substance beneath capacitor. Does this require replacement?

Tags: pc

I was having issues with my PC so I cracked the tower open. In the process of my investigation I looked at my eSATA card and noticed on the opposite side of the circuit board from the capacitor it appears to have been some dried up substance. 
[image]

I believe this issue is unrelated to my original problem, but is this something to be concerned with - and does this warrant a new eSATA card?

Here it the top, with the capacitor in question. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a leaked capacitor, you could repair it yourself if you are comfortable with that, but hiring a repairman might be more expensie than a new card. Atleast if you're in the usa where labor is more expensive than parts.

I'll post some resources for a diy repair tomorrow, it"s a cheap project to try with a card that isn't going to get any less dead otherwise.

http://www.overclockers.com/how-anyone-can-replace-leaking-capacitors/
Here's a quick guide. If you damage the board some solder over the traces should be enough to fix 'er.

As jmy1000 mentioned, if she's under warranty I'd recommend going that route if possible.

Comment: Though I agree that it's a leaked capacitor, buying a replacement part isn't necessarily the best option. If an RMA is available I'd do that; if OP has a soldering iron on hand, then replacing a capacitor that large is fairly trivial even without lots of prior experience.

Comment: I completely forgot about that!, rma'ing would definitely be the simplest solution if it's available.